# W2ui grid Scroll

Tags: w2ui

I want to scrollIntoView a record when the grid has been sort. This is what I'm using:

```
onSort: function(event) {
    event.onComplete = function () {
       w2ui.grid.scrollIntoView(10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delay the `scrollIntoView()`

https://jsfiddle.net/zxcgxkxa/1/

```
onSort: function(event) {
   event.onComplete = function () {
       setTimeout(function(){
           w2ui.grid.scrollIntoView(10);
       }, 10);           
    };
}
```

because after `grid.sort()` is executed, w2grid will internally execute `grid.refresh()`, which internally executes a delayed scrolling:

```
        setTimeout(function () { // allow to render first
            obj.resize(); // needed for horizontal scroll to show (do not remove)
            obj.scroll();
        }, 1);
```